# Propensity Score Matching using Match command to estimate ATT in a binary outcome variable

Tags: r, binary, match, difference, propensity-score-matching

I want to use the Matching package and the Match command in R to use propensity score matching to estimate the ATT (Average Treatment Effect on the Treated) for a binary outcome variable or a count outcome variable (poisson).  It appears that the Match command only allows for a continuous outcome variable.  My code for the continuous variable is:

`glm1 <- glm(Tr~age + educ + black + etc.)` to estimate the propensity scores in a logit or probit model.

`m1 <- Match(Y=Y, Tr=Tr, X=glm1$fitted, estimand="ATT", M=1, ties=TRUE, replace=TRUE)` to estimate the ATT of the Treatment exposure on the Outcome Variable Y.

How do I estimate this for a binary or count outcome variable in R?

My analysis is further complicated by the fact that I want to estimate the difference in differences, not just the post outcome in the Treated minus the post outcome in the Control group.  So, I want to estimate (Outcome (post - pre) in Treated) minus (Outcome (post - pre) in Control).  When the outcome variable is continuous, I believe I can just subtract the mean outcomes for Treated and Control and use that as my new outcome variable with the Match procedure (`Y <- cbind(YDIFF)`).  However, if I have a binary outcome variable or count outcome variable, how do I incorporate this to obtain the difference-in-differences estimate in my propensity score-matched sample?

Answer (score 0):

Everything would work just the same for 1/0 target variables. Only you wouldn't be looking at the average of the target variable, but the average frequency (which is calculated the same way because mean outcome becomes frequency). So from a coding point of view, there is no difference if you are interested in a binary outcome variable.